# c++ streaming udp data into a queue?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, udp, unreal-engine4

I am streaming data as a string over UDP, into a Socket class inside Unreal engine. This is threaded, and runs in the background.

My read function is:

```
float translate;
void FdataThread::ReceiveUDP()
{

    uint32 Size;
    TArray<uint8> ReceivedData;

    if (ReceiverSocket->HasPendingData(Size))
    {
        int32 Read = 0;
        ReceivedData.SetNumUninitialized(FMath::Min(Size, 65507u));
        ReceiverSocket->RecvFrom(ReceivedData.GetData(), ReceivedData.Num(), Read, *targetAddr);
    }

    FString str = FString(bytesRead, UTF8_TO_TCHAR((const UTF8CHAR *)ReceivedData));
    translate = FCString::Atof(*str);

}
```

I then call the `translate` variable from another class, on a `Tick`, or timer.

My test case sends an incrementing number from another application.

If I print this number from inside the above Read function, it looks as expected, counting up incrementally.
When i print it from the other thread, it is missing some of the numbers.

I believe this is because I call it on the Tick, so it misses out some data due to processing time.

My question is:

Is there a way to queue the incoming data, so that when i pull the value, it is the next incremental value and not the current one? What is the best way to go about this?

Thank you, please let me know if I have not been clear.

Comment: You have not been clear. You are denying in comments the existence of a `while` loop that you have plainly posted in your question.

Comment: Ah, I apologize, i created this question late at night, and pasted the wrong code block. I have updated to the `if` loop that should be there.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the complete code? ReceivedData isn't used after it's filled with data from the socket. Instead, an (in this code) undefined variable 'buffer' is being used.

Also, it seems that the while loop could run multiple times, overwriting old data in the ReceivedData buffer. Add some debugging messages to see whether RecvFrom actually reads all bytes from the socket. I believe it reads only one 'packet'.

Finally, especially when you're using UDP sockets over the network, note that the UDP protocol isn't guaranteed to actually deliver its packets. However, I doubt this is causing your problems if you're using it on a single computer or a local network.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, i am sorry, i had a typo in my question, `buffer` should have been `ReceivedData`.

Answer (score 0):

Your read loop doesn't make sense. You are reading and throwing away all datagrams but the last in any given sequence that happen to be in the socket receive buffer at the same time. The translate call should be inside the loop, and the loop should be `while(true)`, or `while (running)`, or similar.

Comment: Hi, As stated, this function is called on a `Tick`, or timer. Therefore, no while loop.

Comment: @anti There is a `while` loop 'as stated' in the code you posted. I can't comment on code I haven't seen, but I am commenting accurately on what you posted.